# LNK2005 invoked by non-template functions exclusively

Tags: c++, templates, unique, lnk2005

I have a C++ namespace called ShapeBuilder containing a collection of template functions that helps draw different shapes of tiles in a tile-based game (square, line etc). **Every function in this namespace used templates without error** until I tried writing a non-template function - something simple like

```
void hey() { printf("Hey"); }
```

Which invoked the following errors:

```
1>HouseGenerator.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl ShapeBuilder::hey(void)" (?hey@ShapeBuilder@@YAXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
1>WorldBuilder.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl ShapeBuilder::hey(void)" (?hey@ShapeBuilder@@YAXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
```

- WorldBuilder uses the namespace ShapeBuilder (and, obviously,
  includes ShapeBuilder.h).
- HouseGenerator is a friend class of WorldBuilder, and includes WorldBuilder.h
- All of the ShapeBuilder code is written in ShapeBuilder.h, which includes WorldBuilder.h
- I have indeed used #pragma once, in all relevant classes, to prevent
  Recursive Inclusion.

Replacing the top code with the following will remove the error.

```
template <class T>
void hey() { printf("Hey"); }
```

So technically I could just put the template declaration in front of all of the functions, but I'm pretty sure I would burn in hell for it. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Change the function to be `inline`.

   ```
   inline void hey() { printf("Hey"); }
   ```
2. Declare the function in the header file but don't define it. Define it in a .cc file.

Comment: That does work, but when it comes down to it I won't want the functions to be inline once they start getting big. Perhaps defining it in the .cpp will work, but it's killing me as to why this happens.

Comment: When you use `#include "file.h"` in a .cpp file, the cpp file gets compiled with everything that got included in it. When a .h file contains a fully defined function and the .h files gets included in multiple compilation units, the function gets defined multiple times.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense enough. Then why would preceding the header definition with the template declaration solve the problem?

Comment: When you have a function template, without definition, the compilation units won't know how to define a function given a template parameter.